# MongoDB _id length getting as 25

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to remove a document from MongoDB using nodeJS.

My code flow is as below:
1.The user can delete a particular student.
2.So I have pulled all the student documents fron the DB and stored in students object.
3. User can filter the search with the textbox provided and can select a particular student and can delete that.

Please find the below UI:

[image: UI]

The HTML page as below:

```
<h2 align="center">Delete Student</h2>
<div ng-controller="deleteStudentController">
<form ng-submit="deleteStudent()">
    Student Name:<input type="text" letters-only ng-model="searchName"/><br>
    <div ng-repeat="student in students | filter:searchName" ng-show="searchName.length">
        <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.studentRadio" name="studentRadio" value="{{student._id}}"/>{{student | formatter}}
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Delete Student"/>
    {{output}}
    </form>
    </div>
```

The angularJS controller associated with the UI is as below:

```
mainApp.controller("deleteStudentController", function($scope,$http) {
var resData = {};
$scope.student = {};
var urlGet = "/students/all";
$http.get(urlGet)
.then(function(response) {
    $scope.students = angular.fromJson(response.data);
});
$scope.deleteStudent = function(){
    var urlDelete = "/students/remove:"+$scope.studentRadio;
    $http.delete(urlDelete)
    .success(function(response, status, headers, config){
        $scope.output = "Student successfully deleted.";
    })
    .error(function(response, status, headers, config){
        $scope.output = "Error in processing. Please try again.";
    });
    }
    });
```

Which inturn calls the node controller:

```
router.delete("/remove:studId", function(req,res){
Students.remove(req.params.studId, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    else {
      var respOut = "Student deleted";
      res.send(respOut);
    }
});
});
```

Inside the controller, there is an object of student model, in which the DB communication is made. I have used mongodb.ObjectID.createFromHexString() method to create objectID from the _id value that I got from the DB

The student model code to delete a document:

```
exports.remove = function(studentId, cb) {
var collection = db.get().collection('students');
console.log("_id"+studentId);
console.log("Length---->"+studentId.length);
collection.remove({_id: mongodb.ObjectID.createFromHexString(studentId)}, function(err) {
  if (err) {
      throw err;
  }
  else {
     cb(err);
     console.log("Record deleted.");
  }
 });
 }
```

But its giving the error as "Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters". So I tried to log the _id value that I got from the DB student document and its length. Surprisingly I am getting the length as '25'.

Please find the below console out that I am getting:

_id:576aba09090560f80bd2caaa
Length---->25

Any idea about this issue? Please help.....

Comment: The length of the _id above is 24. What exactly is `studentId`? How do you get it?

Comment: yes. But Iam getting the length as 25. I made a console out :
console.log("Length---->"+studentId.length);
Not sure why its giving as length 25.:(

Comment: @JohnyHK I have updated my question. Could you please have a look? Please let me know if I need to provide anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Angular code is setting the endpoint like this:

```
"/students/remove:"+$scope.studentRadio
```

I assume that you want the `:` to be there, so the URL will look something like this:

```
/students/remove:576c1d4781aaa4f16a68af24
```

Your Express route looks like this:

```
router.delete("/remove:studId", ...)
```

`:` is a special character in Express routes (it declares a [named parameter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp#named-parameters) called `studId`). This means that your route will take everything after `/remove` to be the value of `studId`, *including* the colon that's in the URL. So `req.params.studId` is `:576c1d4781aaa4f16a68af24`, which has a length of 25 characters.

If you want to use this sort of URL scheme, you need to make the colon to be part of the match by escaping it (so it loses its special meaning):

```
router.delete("/remove\\::studId", ...)
```